# Linux cut pattern from log file

Tags: json, linux, logging, cut

i have json log file but theres not only json
i need to cut/remove everything what isnt json, structure looks like this:

```
 2010-10-10 10:10:10 vibez.dev and here starts json {xxxx:xxxx, etc}
 when json ends, next line with same info begins.
```

i tried cut -d command but it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the work:

```
less file.json | awk -F ' {' '{printf("{%s}\n", $2)}' > result.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -e 's/^.*\{/{/' [logfile]
```

This should remove everything before the first curly bracket in each line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the JSON code starts in the 4th column of a space delimited file, you can simply use

```
cut -f 4- -d ' ' foo.txt
```

to get the JSON code